# Python : comparing word by word : first and last letter (alphabetical order)

Tags: python

I want to compare n words. The first and last letter of the word has to be the same and the next word has to start with end and end with the next letter in the alphabet. If all words are correct you print 'ok'.

For example: 3 liverpool MaM nelson

'ok'

```
n = int(input("Input a number: "))

woorden = []

for i in range(n):
    woord = input("Enter a string: ")
    woorden.append(woord)
    if woord[:1].startswith('"') == woord[:-1].endswith('"'): 
    if ord(woord[:-1]) == ord(woord[:1]):
        print('ok')
    else:
        print(f'{woord}')
```

Comment: "If all words are correct you print 'ok'" but you print ok when the first word is OK.

Answer (score 0):

your if\else indent are bad.
you need to do the printing part only after checking the entire items , AKA , after the loop.

```
n = int(input("Input a number: "))
allGood = True
woorden = []

for i in range(n):
    woord = input("Enter a string: ")
    woorden.append(woord)
    if woord[:1].startswith('"') == woord[:-1].endswith('"'): 
    if ord(woord[:-1]) != ord(woord[:1]):
        allGood = False

print allGood
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this:

```
>>> n = int(input("Input a number: "))
Input a number: 3
>>> woorden = []
>>> for i in range(n):
        word = raw_input('Enter a string: ')
        woorden.append(word)
        if word[0] != word[-1]:
            break
        if i==0:
            previous_char = ord(word[0].lower())
            continue
        if ord(word[0].lower()) != (previous_char+1):
            break
        previous_char = ord(word[0].lower())
    else:
        print 'Ok'


Enter a string: liverpool
Enter a string: MaM
Enter a string: nelson

Ok
```

Comment: What if the words are: Zanz Alicia ? He doesn't think A follows up on Z and sees this as a mistake instead of OK.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this as the expected output

```
Input a number: 5
Enter a string: This
Enter a string: test
Enter a string: is
is
Enter a string: true
Enter a string: fine
ok
```

Code

```
n = int(input("Input a number: "))
x = []
ok = False
for i in range(0,n):
    woord = input("Enter a string: ")
    if i > 0:
        y = ord(woord[:1].lower()) -96
        z = ord(woord[-1].lower())-96
        x.append(y)
        x.append(z)
        if x[c-1] - y == -1:
            ok = True
        else:
            print(f'{woord}')
            ok = False
        c=c+2
    else:
        x.append(ord(woord[-1].lower())-96)
        c=1
if (ok):
    print('ok')
```

For the scenario mentioned in question

```
Input a number: 3
Enter a string: liverpool
Enter a string: MaM
Enter a string: nelson
ok
```

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to be working for all case but not in case of the words: 'Zhanaz' followed by 'Alicia'.
Anyone knows how to solve this?

```
n = int(input("Input a number: "))
    woorden = []

    for i in range(n):
        woord = input("Enter a string: ")
        woorden.append(woord)
        if woord[0].lower() != woord[-1].lower():
            print(f'{woord}')
            break
        if i == 0:
            previous_char = ord(woord[0].lower())
            continue
        if ord(woord[0].lower()) != (previous_char+1):
            print(f'{woord}')
            break
        previous_char = ord(woord[0].lower())

    else:
        print('Ok')
```